# How to import two spreadsheets in mysql using PHPMyADMIN?

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin, opendocument

I imported a spreadsheet `mdetail.ods` using `PHPMyADMIN` in  `mysql` database named as mdv.
After it was imported filename **sheet1** appears in the database `mdv`. And again I import another spreadsheet `ndetails.ods` but this time the filename **sheet1** is updated.

The filename is same but the content is replaced with the data of `ndetails.ods`.
How can I import both of the files in same database?
Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

phpMyAdmin is assuming the sheet name as the table name.

Either

- Rename the sheet in the .ods file before import

or

- Import the first one and rename the table that has been created before you import the second one

I rather suspect "Sheet1" is not what you want your tables to be called anyway

Comment: Thnx @Darren H. That was  such a silly thing  I was not prefering. Thanx